# Rails console find all items which have none of the following names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the `rails c` I am trying to find all pages that do not have the comma separated names using the following:

`Page.where.not(name: "One, Two, Three")`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Page.where.not(name: ["One","Two","Three"])
```